# How to store credentials for different environments .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am developing an app in .NET Core 2.1 on windows, but this is going to be deployed on a Linux server. I am looking for a way to store secrets for both development and production without having to have separate code paths for reading the credentials.

In .NET Core, the [secret manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows) could be used to store credentials, but the docs says this should only be used for development. After doing some research, looks like the environment variables are the way to go (correct me if I am wrong). I could add the environment variables by going to `Project -> Properties -> Debug -> Environment variables`, but this adds the variables to the `launchSettings.json` which makes it pointless for my purpose.

So I think I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to add and read environment variables for a project
   in the visual studio without having to write it in a config file?
2. What are other options for storing secrets for
   both dev and prod so we don't have to have a separate code path to read them?

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core secrets work in both Windows and Linux.
Remember that the secrets don't "travel" with your application.
You will need to set the secret on each machine that you deploy the application to.

As you mentioned, it's also possible to use Environment Variables for storing secrets. However, this means that you'll need to perform the encryption/decryption yourself.

You also have the option of encrypting secrets on that file system. This comes with most of the same drawbacks as encrypting them and storing them in the Environment Variables.

Another option (that's not quite a popular with the advent of .NET Core) is to use "aspnet_regiis" to encrypt your web.config. I only recommend that route with .NET Framework.
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/877258/How-to-Encrypt-Web-config-Using-aspnet-regiis-exe

Comment: The docs says "The Secret Manager tool doesn't encrypt the stored secrets and shouldn't be treated as a trusted store. It's for `development purposes` only". For your second paragraph, my question was how? I obviously don't want to use OS-level env vars.

Comment: You're correct. I really thought that the .NET Secret Manager was encrypting the data, but the docs say that it doesn't. You still have the option of putting your keys in a location that only the appropriate user can access. If the drive is encrypted, this at least provides you with *some* protection.